# Identifying range of x array indices to set corresponding y array values to zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

Say I have data in `t` and `y` arrays. I want to identify the array element indices between t=0.5 to t=1.5 and t=3 to t=4 in order to set the corresponding y values to zero (and put this in `ynew` array). I am having trouble with getting the indices into the empty array `tnew`, as I just get an output of `[]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.array([0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.88,0.92,1.09,1.2,1.28,1.5,1.7,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.33,2.6,2.9,2.99,3.1,3.3,3.4,3.7,3.8,4,4.2])
y = t + 0.2*np.random.randn(len(t))

plt.plot(t,y,'o')
plt.show()

# want ranges t=0.5 to t=1.5 and t=3 to t=4 to have corresponding y=0 values:
for index, item in enumerate(t):
    tnew = [] # put index values here
    if item > 0.5 and item < 1.5:
        tnew.append(index)
        #print (index, item)
    elif item > 3 and item < 4:
        tnew.append(index)
        #print (index, item)

print (tnew)
```

Any ideas?

I want to end up plotting `ynew` vs `tnew`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the boolean indexing of `numpy`.

Add this line: `y[((t>0.5)&(t<=1.5))|((t>3)&(t<=4))]=0.`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
for index, item in enumerate(t):
    tnew = [] # put index values here
    if item > 0.5 and item < 1.5:
        tnew.append(index)
        #print (index, item)
    elif item > 3 and item < 4:
        tnew.append(index)
```

You replace `tnew` with an empty list every time round the loop, so you will have at most one index (the last!) in it afterwards.

Instead, try:

```
tnew = []
for index, item in enumerate(t):
    if (0.5 < item < 1.5) or (3 < item < 4):
        tnew.append(index)
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
tnew = [index for index, item in enumerate(t) 
        if (0.5 < item < 1.5) or (3 < item < 4)]
```

Comment: So how would I set the corresponding `y` values to zero? It's not just a trivial matter of `for i in tnew:` and `y[i] = 0`.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want; isn't `ynew` just all zeroes and the same length as `tnew`? Perhaps add a shorter input and example output to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to identify the corresponding `y` array values - the indices are specified in `tnew`. Then I want to set these `y` values to 0. This new array would be called `ynew`. Is this clearer?

Comment: So the values in `ynew` are extracted from the corresponding indices of `y`, *after which* they're set to zero in `y`?

Comment: Correct. Also, see CT Zhu's answer.